# Can Chart.js accept css font size for responsive interface?

Tags: css, chart.js, font-size

I need to change the font-size depending on screen size just changing a class (i.e.: sm, lg, xl ...)

Is there any way to change font size for ticks or labels using css?

Comment: Please check this documentation https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html

Comment: No since the ticks are not Dom elements you can't style them with css